# SetInterval stops running for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I refresh a clock display using setInterval every 100ms, but at some point it stops running.

When I start my script, it works fine, but then, later, the clock isn't updated anymore. I don't have any clue why and debug seems difficult this it happens randomly after douzen of minutes.

I'm running the script as userscript in another webpage, maybe it is related, or maybe something goes wrong, like a non catched exception somewhere that stops my script, but so far I didn't see anything in the console...

I'm thinking about using SetTimeout calling itself instead, but I wanted to ask here before, maybe you have some good advice to debug or understand this issue.

```
setInterval(function(){
    app.displayClock();
}, app.ensureMinMax(app.settings('CLOCK_DELAY_REFRESH'), 0, 1000));
```

Function called:

```
/**
 * Display/refresh the displayed clock.
 */
app.displayClock = function(){
    app.waitForDOM(function(){
        var id = '__shared_clock';
        var idTime = '__shared_clock_text';
        var idForm = '__shared_clock_form';
        var $selector = $j('#container-top');

        if($selector.has('#'+id).length){
            // Retrieve existing element.
            $selector.has('#'+id).find('#'+idTime).html(app._getTime(
                true,
                parseInt($selector.find('#'+idForm).find('#__shared_clock_form_hours').val()),
                parseInt($selector.find('#'+idForm).find('#__shared_clock_form_minutes').val()),
                parseInt($selector.find('#'+idForm).find('#__shared_clock_form_seconds').val())
            ));
        }else{
            // Create main container, sub containers and bind events.
            $selector.append($j('<div/>', {
                id: id
            }));

            if(app.settings('DISPLAY_CLOCK_CALCULATOR')) {
                // Create area that contains a form.
                $selector.find('#' + id).append($j('<div/>', {
                    id: idForm,
                    html:// Inverse the order because there are floating!
                        '<input type="text" id="__shared_clock_form_seconds" size="3" style="float: right;color: whitesmoke;" tabindex="10002" placeholder="Sec" />'+
                        '<input type="text" id="__shared_clock_form_minutes" size="3" style="float: right;color: whitesmoke;" tabindex="10001" placeholder="Min" />'+
                        '<input type="text" id="__shared_clock_form_hours" size="3" style="float: right;color: whitesmoke;" tabindex="10000" placeholder="Hour" />'
                }));
            }

            // Create area that contains the time value.
            $selector.find('#'+id).append($j('<div/>', {
                id: idTime,
                style: 'float: right; margin-top: 8px; padding-right: 10px;',
                html: app._getTime()
            }));
        }
    });
};
```

The code is quite big and use function that I do not share because they are also quite big and use function ...

Basically, the setInterval call is made in the main script.
The waitForDom ensure that the DOM is loaded before to try to change it, and no, using the usual jQuery wait for dom doesn't work here.

Comment: We can't do anything without your code.

Comment: I have added the source code but I don't really think that will be helpful :/